# why am i getting an "ArgumentError (given 4, expected 2)" in #create when .permit is taking 9 arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My Items controller was working just fine until recently. I create a new Item and get `ArgumentError in ItemsController#create wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 2)` Why would .`build(item_params)` suddenly no longer work? It works in other controllers.

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @item = current_user.owned_items.build(item_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "Thanks! You will be notified when your submission is approved." }
        format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def item_params
   params.require(:item).permit(:image, :artist, :title, :medium, :year, :price, :length, :height, :width)
  end
end
```

Comment: ok nevermind. this was caused by a change I made to a process in my CarrierWave::MiniMagick file. i had `resize_to_limit` taking 4 arguments, but it can only take 2.

Comment: if you figure out your own question, you can post an answer or close it but you don't need to leave it open.

Comment: @maxpleaner I will when the site will let me accept my own answer. The options for closing aren't 'right'. It's not too broad, it's not a duplicate, it includes an example of working code, it's not unclear, and it's not opinion-based. If whoever downvoted could please undo that, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I downvoted before you posted the answer, it was to indicate to other people that it wasn't a good question to read through, because it already had an answer at that point really. I can't reverse the downvote now, it's too late. No hard feelings - just keep posting questions, and you'll recover the points easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a change I made to a process in my CarrierWave::MiniMagick file. I had resize_to_limit taking 4 arguments, but it can only take 2.